# iPhone UDP ad hoc datas transfert

Tags: iphone, objective-c, udp, adhoc

I'm trying to make an iPhone application to communicate with an other wireless device.
The other device can send datas via UDP sockets. I just want to know if it is possible to receive the informations on the iPhone, without access point on the network (just an iPhone and the wireless device), and how if it is.

I was looking at UDPecho, by apple, and I think it could be useful.

If anyone had some idea, just let me know what you're thinking about

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3 can create a Wi-Fi network using the Personal Hotspot feature, which your "other device" could join.

A Verizon iPhone with 4.2.6 may also be able to do this.

Earlier iPhone models can't use the Personal Hotspot feature, regardless of the version of iOS.

Comment: Yes I know that you can use personal Hotspot feature but it depends on your provider. And even it is possible on all iPhone, how do you do in the code to activate it (or you connect the other device before laucnhing the app), what do you think?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you use Personal Hotspot as a tethering solution. Presumably that's what you're after with your modem. I'm saying you might be able to create the Wi-Fi network on your iPhone using Personal Hotspot. My guess is that this won't work unless you have a tethering plan, though, so chances are pretty good you can't do what you want.